# Difference in adding a たとえ

Tags: word-choice

Whats the difference in using a たとえ in a sentence. For example:

**たとえ**行かなくてもいいんだ

行かなくてもいいんだ

From what I understand, even without using たとえ, the sentence already mean " *even* if you don't go, it's ok". So what's the point in adding たとえ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [「たとえ + ても」 vs just 「ても」, what is the role of たとえ？ Is it just emphasis or something more?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/58702/%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a8%e3%81%88-%e3%81%a6%e3%82%82-vs-just-%e3%81%a6%e3%82%82-what-is-the-role-of-%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a8%e3%81%88-is-it-just-emphasis-or-somethi)

Answer (score 1):

Let's compare some sentences:

1A  くびになっても真実を言うつもりだ。
1B  たとえくびになっても真実を言うつもりだ。

2A  本当だとしても証拠がない。
2B  たとえ本当だとしても証拠がない。

3A  彼が何と言っても言うことを聞くな。
3B  たとえ彼が何と言っても言うことを聞くな。

1: Even if it costs me my job, I will tell the truth.

2: Even granting that it's true, there is no evidence.

3: No matter what he says, you must not listen to him.

In these examples, the meaning of A and B are practically the same. Even though A don't have "たとえ", they already imply the meaning of "even" ("ても" functions as "even if").

But B (using "たとえ") emphasize the part "even if". The first part of each sentences may not happen, but even if it happens, the second part wouldn't be changed.

Comment: so all たとえ does is it places and emphasis on the "even if"? whereas without it, it's a weaker even if?